# Construct an array of objects using another array of objects and a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of object like this:

```
channels=[
  {name: mega, status: true},
  {name: ant, status: false},
  {name: apl, status: true}
]
```

and I have a single object with this format

```
obj = {0: false, 1: true}
```

The keys in the plain object represent indexes of the `channels` array. The `status` properties must be updated.

For the above example data `channels` should be updated to:

```
channels=[
  {name: mega, status: false},
  {name: ant, status: true},
  {name: apl, status: true}
]
```

How can I implement this efficiently?

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: If `mega` is supposed to be a string literal, then the quotes are missing (also on the other entries)

Comment: thanks! It's a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the `obj` with any method you like (here I used [**`Object.keys`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of keys from `obj` object and [**`forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through them) and update the field. It can be achieved in one line of code:

```js
const channels = [
  {name: "mega", status: true},
  {name: "ant", status: false},
  {name: "apl", status: true}
];

const obj = {
  "0": false,
  "1": true
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach((item, i) => channels[i].status = obj[i]);

/**
 * If "channels" array is NOT ALWAYS longer than the amount of "obj" properties,
 * you should add the check for existence, the simpliest one is implemented below:
 * 
 * Object.keys(obj).forEach((item, i) => channels[i] ? channels[i].status = obj[i] : null);
 */
console.log(channels);
```

In the provided case, the original array is mutated, and if it's not what you need, I recommend to take a look at [**`map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, it doesn't mutate the original array, it creates a new one instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working finally. Beacause the type of index in the array is a number and the type of key in my object is a string :( It is returning undefined

Comment: @Alex_R, are you sure it's the case? Because I've updated the answer (wrapped keys of `obj` as strings) and it's still working, because it doesn't really matter in this case. Anyway, if the issue is in types only, you can just do `.toString()` and compare strings further.

Comment: OP asked for an *efficient* implementation. If `channels` is large and the updates `obj` is small, the `forEach` loop won't do any good.

Comment: @Bergi, you're right, my fault. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop will do:

```
for (let index in obj) channels[index].status = obj[index];
```

```js
const channels=[{name: "mega", status: true}, {name: "ant", status: false}, {name: "apl", status: true}];

const obj={0: false, 1:true};

for (let index in obj) {
 channels[index].status = obj[index];
}

console.log(channels);
```

If you don't want to mutate the original array, but want a new array with the modifications then:

```js
const channels=[{name: "mega", status: true}, {name: "ant", status: false}, {name: "apl", status: true}];

const obj={0: false, 1:true};

const result = channels.map(({name, status}, i) => 
    ({name, status: i in obj ? obj[i] : status})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop should do it.

```
 for(var key in obj){
       channels[key].status = obj[key]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over `channels` array using `forEach()` and use `Object.assign()` to override property.

```js
let channels = [
  {name: 'mega', status: true },
  {name: 'ant' , status: false},
  {name: 'apl' , status: true }
];

let obj = {
  0: false,
  1: true
};

channels.forEach((o, i) => i in obj ? Object.assign(o, {status: obj[i]}) : o);

console.log(channels);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This leads to `"status": undefined`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I've added a fix.